# How to get data and methods from onther componenet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I'm trying to make a dashboard for a timer on the dashboard you can set alarms that changes the background color of the timer what i want to do is that i want to show the timer on a diffrent page and on that diffrent page i want to see the timer changing background color that i have set on the dashboard page
i used two component and i tried to get the data fron one to another but it didint work out for me
[image: Alarm red]

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
  return {
    
 

      elapsedTime: 0,
      timer: undefined,
      time: 0,
      minutes: 0,
      seconds: 0,
      setMinutes: 0,
      setSeconds: 0,

      nonActiveWarningMinutesRed: 0,
      nonActiveWarningSecondsRed: 0,
      nonActiveWarningMinutesOrange : 0,
      nonActiveWarningSecondsOrange: 0,

      warningMinutesRed: undefined,
      warningSecondsRed: undefined,
      warningMinutesOrange: undefined,
      warningSecondsOrange: undefined,
    };
  },
  
  methods: {
   sendTime() {
        this.minutes = document.getElementById("min").value;
        this.seconds = document.getElementById("sec").value;
    },
    updateWarningRed() {
      console.log(this.nonActiveWarningSecondsRed && this.nonActiveWarningMinutesRed);
      this.warningMinutesRed = this.nonActiveWarningMinutesRed;
      this.warningSecondsRed = this.nonActiveWarningSecondsRed;
    },
    updateWarningOrange() {
      console.log(this.nonActiveWarningSecondsOrange);
      this.warningMinutesOrange = this.nonActiveWarningMinutesOrange;
      this.warningSecondsOrange = this.nonActiveWarningSecondsOrange;
    },
    start() {
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.seconds > 58) {
          this.seconds = 1;
          this.minutes = parseInt(this.minutes) + 1;
        } else {
          this.seconds++;
        }
      }, 1000);
    },
    stop() {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
    },
    reset() {
      this.minutes = 0;
      this.seconds = 0;
        this.warningMinutesRed = undefined;
      this.warningSecondsRed = undefined;
        this.warningMinutesOrange = undefined;
      this.warningSecondsOrange = undefined;
    }
  },
  computed:{
  formattedElapsedTime() {
      const date = new Date(null);
      date.setSeconds(this.seconds);
      date.setMinutes(this.minutes);
      const utc = date.toUTCString();
      return utc.substr(utc.indexOf(":") - 2, 8);
    },
    textColor() {
      if (
        this.warningSecondsRed != null && this.warningMinutesRed != null &&
         
        this.seconds + (this.minutes * 60) >= this.warningSecondsRed + (this.warningMinutesRed * 60) && 
        this.minutes >= this.warningMinutesRed
      ) {
        return 'red';
      } else if (  
        this.warningSecondsOrange != null && this.warningMinutesOrange != null && 
        
        this.seconds + (this.minutes * 60) >= this.warningSecondsOrange + (this.warningMinutesOrange * 60) && 
        this.minutes >= this.warningMinutesOrange) {
        return 'orange';
      }
      return 'black';
    },
  }
})
```

```css
.text-black {
  color: black;
}
.text-orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
.text-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

  <div id="demo">

      <div class="grid  h-screen ">
        
        <p :class="'grid bg-white-600 place-items-center text-5xl ... '+'text-' + textColor">

      <span >
        {{ minutes }}:{{ seconds }}
      </span>

    </p>
     <div class="  flex py-5 space-x-4 justify-center flex-row ...">
     
    <div><button class="bg-green-700 hover:bg-green-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full"
     @click="start">Start</button>
     </div>

    <div><button class="bg-red-700 hover:bg-red-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full" 
    @click="stop">Stop</button>
    </div>

    <div><button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full" 
    @click="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>

   </div>

<div class="flex py-5 space-x-4 justify-center flex-row ...">

    <form class="bg-white px-8 space-x-2  ">
         <input type="number" 
     class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-25 py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
      v-model="minutes" 
      name="time_m" id="min" min="0" max="59">

        <input type="number" 
    class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-25 py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline "  
    v-model="seconds" 
    name="time_s" id="sec" max="59" min="0">

         <button type="button" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-3 rounded" 
     @click="sendTime">Set time</button>

    </form>

    <form class="bg-white  space-x-2 px-8 ">
         <input type="number" 
     class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-25 py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline  "  
     v-model="nonActiveWarningMinutesOrange" 
     name="time_m" id="minWarnOrange" min="0" max="59">

        <input type="number" 
    class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-25 py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline  "  
    v-model="nonActiveWarningSecondsOrange" 
    name="time_s" id="secWarnOrange" max="59" min="0">

         <button type="button" 
     class="bg-orange-600 hover:bg-orange-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-3 rounded" 
     @click="updateWarningOrange">Set warning orange</button>
    </form>

 <form class="bg-white px-8 space-x-2 ">
   
         <input type="number" 
     class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-25 py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline  "  
     v-model="nonActiveWarningMinutesRed" 
     name="time_m1" id="minWarnRed" min="0" max="59">

        <input type="number" 
    class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-25 py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline "  
    v-model="nonActiveWarningSecondsRed" 
    name="time_s1" id="secWarnRed" max="59" min="0">

         <button type="button" 
     class="bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-3 rounded" 
     @click="updateWarningRed">Set warning Red</button>

    </form>
  </div>
    </div>
   
    

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if i understood the question well you want to pass data from parent to child and conversely is it right ? So if it's exactly that you have to use `props` to pass from the parent to the child so from your `Dashboard` to your `child components` and events named `$emit('evenexemple', data)` and call the event at the parent tag to pass data from child to parent from your `child component to your Dashboard`. I let you see the documentation ;)

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: thank you for your answer  i'll check the docs and pos it if it works

Comment: Ok perfect then keep me in touch